# Getting MAC address only from ifconfig

Tags: python, macos, bash, mac-address

I'm trying to use grep to get me en0's mac address. What I'm trying to do is store that in a variable called original_mac.

This does not seem to be working though. When I type `ifconfig en0 | grep ether` i get `ether: <mac_address>`. I just want to get the mac address part of it.

```
#get original mac address
    global original_mac
    original_mac = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig en0 | grep ether | awk {print $2}")
    print "mac: "+original_mac
```

Comment: If you don't have to use the shell, you could be better using [`getnode` in the standard `uuid` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.getnode)

Comment: do you really have to use ifconfig?  or would any python code be ok?

Comment: python code would work too

Answer (score 1):

You have to either pass a list to check_output or use 'shell=True'. So this should work:

```
original_mac = subprocess.check_output("ifconfig en0 | grep ether | awk {print $2}", shell=True)
```

Comment: I get an exception with this. Even when I type it into the terminal as-is it still crashes.

Comment: @magna_nz - you get an `awk` error (which is printed on the screen), so python gets a non-zero return and raises an exception.  You need to put the print in quotes - `subprocess.check_output('ifconfig en0 | grep ether | awk "{print $2}"', shell=True)` should work better.

Comment: OK this is working but it's grabbing `ether <mac address>` when I just want it to grab `<mac address>`